# Is it possible to do any programming on the Microsoft Surface RT?

Tags: microsoft-surface

Is there any way to do some level of actual programming directly on the Surface RT? I expect that (just like with iOS) you need a "real" PC to develop actual apps for it, but perhaps there are some scripting languages available that run directly on the Surface, so for example my son can do some programming exercises on it?

Or would I need to use a web service for that like ideone?

Comment: few years ago i believe it was technically possible to program python apps on symbian smartphones.. It should be technically possible to get atleast scripting languages to work though it might not be ideal

Comment: I do have Python 2.7.3 installed on my iPhone, too. Something like that would be great for Surface...

Comment: Online IDE's.  eg: [Cloud 9](https://c9.io/), http://ideone.com/ etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no App currently available to "practice" programming on Surface RT. Even if an App comes up for this purpose, it will be very controlled and would not be able to match up the features available in a Desktop environment.

And as you said, Ideone seems to be ideal for this purpose and should work in Metro IE without any problems.

Answer (score 6):

My Surface RT just arrived, and I'm pleased to find that PowerShell is included. I guess that's not really a programming language for beginners, but it's a start.

Answer (score 3):

If it's not too late and you don't mind waiting a few months (or dropping extra cash), you can return the RT and purchase the [Surface Pro](http://www.microsoft.com/Surface/en-US/surface-with-windows-8-pro/home) when it comes out.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't bought the Surface yet, and I know about the Pro, but I really want to try the Surface RT (lighter, cheaper, longer battery life, Jeff likes it...)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if they port VS to the Windows RT at some point, I think the public will demand it :-). The Pro is just too thick and heavy for my tastes.

Answer (score 2):

Yay, my favourite language has been made available on Windows RT (by none other than Python guru Martin v. Löwis):  [Python 3 for Metro](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/python-3-for-metro/82f0c953-93d4-461c-893f-c298b0d919d2)

Here's a [related question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14299990/20670).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's a jailbreak, and you can run Python, and Perl, and some others. **Must be compiled for ARM whilst in test mode**

Comment: Actually, you can run x86 programs on the jailbroken Surface RT using [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2095934). But the surface rt has been discontinued ages ago...

Comment: I know. But... but what if. I USE jaiLbREak tODay as MAin PC

Answer (score 0):

One year later after posting your question: YES.

You can use PascalABC.NET, it runs on the Surface RT with Windows 8/8.1 on test mode, and it also runs on the Surface RT upgraded to Windows 10 (yes, there is such thing). PascalABC.NET is quite common in Russia and regarding your question: yes you can run, design and code on the RT, and even build .exe files.

Another option is QuickSharp but I've been unable to create .exe files as it needs extra configuration. But PascalABC on the other hand does it all out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

I found an app called codebox that can compile and run programs in many languages for Windows tablet. I just tested it so don't know what are the limits...